# ReSharper keybinding problems

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 + ReSharper 7. I have the R# visual studio keybinding scheme which uses Ctrl-D to duplicate a line, however this prevents me from using any of the debug window shortcuts - eg. Ctrl-D, L to go to the locals window. Does anyone know what the easiest way to resolve the conflict is? Surely I don't have to go through and reassign all of the debug window shortcuts?

Comment: What about using `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `D` instead to duplicate lines rather than re-assign all the Debug shortcuts that us `CTRL` + `D`?

Comment: Yeah, that would work - but I guess I was hoping that the JetBrains chaps would have addressed this already... I'm just used to the magic that is IntelliJ ;)